# Filling NA's from previous rows, but adding one level

Tags: r, fillna

I have data, where I've used `tidyr::complete(full.sequence(Tenure))` to add new rows to complete my Tenure column, but am then left with NA's in between the ordered Month_Yr.

```
 MemberID Tenure Month_Yr
   <fct>    <dbl> <ord>   
  7            0   2019-02
  7            1   2019-03 
  7            2   2019-04 
  7            3   2019-05 
  7            4   NA
  7            5   NA 
  7            6   NA
  7            7   2019-09
```

I've tried filling the NA's with fill and na.fill, but then it either fills all values with the same value up or down for each individual customer.

```
'''fill(data, Month_Yr, .direction="down")'''
```

I am looking for a code that will take the previous value down, but add one level for each line. So that the output is like this :

```
MemberID Tenure Month_Yr
   <fct>    <dbl> <ord>   
  7            0   2019-02
  7            1   2019-03 
  7            2   2019-04 
  7            3   2019-05 
  7            4   **2019-06**
  7            5   **2019-07** 
  7            6   **2019-08**
  7            7   2019-09
```

Comment: This should be handled in `complete` step itself. Can you share the data on which the `complete` function was applied?

Comment: I've tried applying the same complete steps to the Month_Yr column, but get an error saying: Error in UseMethod("full_seq") : 
  no applicable method for 'full_seq' applied to an object of class "c('ordered', 'factor')"

Comment: The data which you have shared is the one after you have applied `complete` to it, right? Please share the original data.

Comment: MemberID Tenure Month_Yr
   <fct>    <dbl> <ord>   
  7            0   2019-02
  7            1   2019-03 
  7            2   2019-04 
  7            3   2019-05 
  7            7   2019-09  (it would just skip the months were there was no activity)

Comment: Please update your post with the data, the format is not clear in the comments.

Answer (score -1):

you can create a lag of tenure, take the difference and add to the month_yr

```
library(zoo)

df$Month_yr <- na.locf(df$Month_yr)+months(new_col)
```